# finding dsyms for Crashlytics

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

Crashlytics "help article" wasn't helpful. 
https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html

Struggling to kickstart crashlytics for my project.

What have been done:

- test 'crash' button with app crashing code implemented.
- built, crashed.
- crashlytics detected the app, but shows "missing dsyms"
- in xcode, targets-> MyApp -> Build Settings -> Debug Info Format -> Dwarf with dsym file.
- Product -> Archive
- right click on archive -> show in finder -> show package contents, dSYMs folder -> along with frameworks dsyms located MyApp.app.dsym file. Archived it with terminal `zip -r SymbolFiles.zip MyApp.app.dSYM`("compress .." simply didn't work)
- uploaded that zip to crashlytics. Said "return in couple minutes". Nothing happened, "missing dsyms" persists.

Article suggests to search for missing UUID while running `dwarfdump -u <PathToYourAppsDsym>`
in which case, i get an error: `parse error near`\n'`

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you share the full command your running with the replaced value for <PathToYourAppsDsym>? Based on what you posted, my guess is that the dSYM that was uploaded doesn't match the one reported as missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue got resolved.

1. The latest Xcode(8.3.2) now has 4 columns for Debug Info:
   [image]

​​
It worked after double checking everywhere "Dwarf with dSYM".

2. Somehow, I missed the step that after crashing the app, I had to again relaunch it from the device, not simulator.

Comment: I set both DEBUG DWARF with dlsym file. When I upload dsym from Xcode finder , it provides me a debug dysym and I upload it to crashlytics, test crash,  I get crash on dashboard. But when i download the dysym from iTunes and upload to crashlytics, it's not showing crash. What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

@Evgeny is right. Setting the Debug Information Format to DWARF with dSYM File will be right.

Comment: I set both DEBUG DWARF with dlsym file. When I upload dsym from Xcode finder , it provides me a debug dysym and I upload it to crashlytics, test crash,  I get crash on dashboard. But when i download the dysym from iTunes and upload to crashlytics, it's not showing crash. What can I do ?